# Coriolis with finite difference Method Matlab

Tags: matlab, math, numerical-methods

I'm trying to create an algorithm to plot the trajectory of a moving parcel on a rotating frame of reference. On the parcel effects only the Coriolis fictitious force. The motion is described by

[image: motionEq]

where [image: fParameter]

Formulating the above equations in the finite difference form
[image: finiteU]
so the coordinates of the parcel would be
[image: coord]

The part of the code that calculates and plots the coords is

```
x=zeros(1,T/Dt)
y=zeros(1,T/Dt)

x(1)=x0
y(1)=y0
i = 0
for t = 1:Dt:T
    i = i + 1
    u1 = u0 + Dt*f*u0;
    v1 = v0 - Dt*f*v0;

    x(i+1) = x(i) + Dt*u1;
    y(i+1) = y(i) + Dt*v1;

    u0 = u1; v0 = v1;        

end

plot(x,y,'-*')
```

The resulting plot is
[image: plot]

I'm not satisfied by the end result and I'm wondering if my code implementation is done right. I would expect something more like a spiral or circular motion.
An example result should be
[image: example]
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: f depends on the velocity and so will not be constant,

Comment: @dmuir The coriolis parameter f is constant for motions less than 100km in radius according to the f-plane approximation. Even then, f depends on the angular velocity (Omega) of the rotating frame.